# Ошибка при создании AppBundle

Tags: android-studio, android-bundle

Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? Ошибка выскакивает при создании AppBundle:

```
Cause: buildOutput.apkData must not be null
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня было по-моему такое один раз, решил проблему так:

1. `Build -> Clean Project`
2. `Build -> Make Project`

при том что градл у меня такой версии:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha03'
```

где-то нашел такой способ и вроде помогло, надеюсь и вам поможет тоже. Если не получится, напишите, будем решать проблему иначе.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло